# Find all primes p such that $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory

Find all primes $p>2$ such that $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}$ is a perfect square.

My try:
Since $p>2$, we can write

$\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}=\frac{(2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1)(2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1)}{p}=n^2$
Now since p is a prime one of the $(2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1)$ and $(2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1)$

case-1

$p|(2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1)$

$(2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1)=pk$

hence $n^2=k(pk+2)$

writing   $k=m^2t$ where $t$ doesn't contain any perfect square divisor

$a^2=t(pm^2t+2)$

This indicates that t is either $1$ or $2$.

Putting $t=1$

$a^2=pm^2+2$

hence

$a^2=2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1$

$(a-1)(a+1)=2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$

It can easily be shown that $a=3$ is the only solution to this equation hence $p=7$ is the only solution in case-1.(putting $t=2$ doesn't give any solution.)

Similar method gives $p=3$ in case-2

But someone told me there is an elegent and novel method to solve it. I tried but i didn't get it. Please help.

Comment: Please describe the novel method!

Comment: It seems you proved that $p=3$ and $p=7$ are the only solutions. So what exactly is the question ?